# OR in WHERE statement slowing things down dramatically

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have the following query that finds customers related to an order. I have a legacy ID on the customer so I have to check old id (legacy) and customer id hence the or statement

```
SELECT  
   c.Title, 
   c.Name   
  FROM productOrder po   
      INNER JOIN Employee e ON po.BookedBy = e.ID
      CROSS APPLY (
      SELECT TOP 1 *
      FROM Customer c 
      WHERE(po.CustID = c.OldID OR po.CustID = c.CustID)    
      ) c

  GROUP BY     
  c.CustomerId, c.Title, c.FirstName, c.LastName
```

if I remove the `OR` statement it runs fine for both situations. There is an index on customer id and legacy.

Comment: Do you have separate indexes on `customer.oldid` and `customer.custid` ?

Comment: No, I have a clustered index

Comment: Why not update `productOrder` and replace the old id:s with the corresponding new id:s? Assuming that old id:s are also unique in `customer` that should be easy... What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For table `customer`, you need to create separate indexes on columns `oldid` and `custid`. If you already have clustered index on `custid`, then add index on `oldid` as well:

```
CREATE INDEX customer_oldid_idx ON customer(oldid);
```

Without this index, search for `oldid` in this clause:

```
 WHERE (po.CustID = c.OldID OR po.CustID = c.CustID)
```

will have to use full table scan, and that will be super slow.